# Clicking Help->Business on Meta overwrites meta but doesn't overwrite SO - why the difference?

Tags: bug, top-bar

The growing menu within help has added a new menu item **Business**.  Clicking `help->business` within stackoverflow opens this item in a new window, that is:

`<a href="businesspage.html" target="_blank">`

Whilst selecting `help->business` within meta overwrites meta completely and I lose my personal navigation bar allowing me to navigate stackexchange.

Why does this action of clicking business on the meta site overwrite meta but not stackoverflow?

[image]

Also this menu seems to be growing, it may be worthwhile to organize the categories.  I'm not sure why the tour, help center, and whats meta are all separate links.  This should be cleaned up a bit.

### See comments

Suddenly this is working however I'd like to point out that this functionality does not seem normal.

I tend to dislike new windows open but from a UX perspective this is shall we say not recommended practices of breaking ones rhythm.

In this case, the business site has nothing to do with meta or stackoverflow - its in its own world. Opening it on top of the current site is wrong since so/meta is a site that allows logging / sessions so you've just taken me out of that context.

It (The business page) should open `target=_blank`, and although many have mentioned that is rarely followed in SO, I can assure you that in jobs within SO `target=_blank` is used a lot more.

Comment: Not sure I follow this one.  I see the same behavior on both Meta and the regular site when I click it.  I get taken to a new page (nothing opens in a new tab/window).  Am I misunderstanding your issue

Comment: Strange now they are both the same, I just tried this (I swear!) and in SO it was opening in a new window while meta wasn't.  Actually this still should be an open ticket as I believe this site should open in a new window, breaking my rhythm is not good.  Overwriting the site that has a personal navigation and not providing it in the business site isn't good.

Comment: Stack Exchange has had a very long history of trying not to open things in new windows.  None of them items in the Help menu open in a new window.  To change it for just this would lead to inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - the other items maintain the top navigation bar - that is they are part of the site.  Business is NOT part of the site.

Comment: Ok, I see that point then

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I tend to dislike new windows open but from a UX perspective this is shall we say **not recommended** practices of breaking  ones rhythm.  In this case, the business site has nothing to do with meta or stackoverflow - its in its own world.  Opening it on top of the current site is wrong since so/meta is a site that allows logging / sessions so you've just taken me out of that context.  It should open target=_blank, and although you've mentioned that is rarely followed in SO, I can assure you that in jobs within SO target=_blank is used a lot more.

Comment: But if you came to the site looking to hire someone or post an ad you probably *don't* want to keep an extra window/tab open with site questions on it.

Comment: @BSMP - Many roles within SO (including my own role) has me hiring people as well as programming.  That is I am a working supervisor that doesn't just manage people but actually both coding and managing people.  I need to do both.

Comment: If the claim made in the title was based on a misobservation (which it appears to be; I can't repro it either), then you should edit the title to make it more clear what you're actually proposing here. Changing the question so drastically would be frowned upon if you'd already received an answer, but no one has answered this. Probably because they aren't sure what you're saying---I'm certainly not. It *looks* like you're suggesting that the link open in a new window. I cannot support that. If I wanted a new window, I'd use the standard mechanisms to get one. It's not the site's decision.